# Collision detection in Processing 3

Tags: java, processing

[image]I have a some circular objects on my screen that are stored in arrays and I want to know if the mouse cursor is hovering over one. Here is what I hav done:

```
//this gives me the coordination of a circle 
     float [] coordinates() {
        float f[] = new float[2];
        //println("x \t" + super.x + "\t y" + super.y);
        f[0] = super.x;
        f[1] = super.y;
      return f;
    }
```

and I store all in an array called chosen which i iterate through:

```
  for (int k = 0; k< chosen.size(); k++) {

    if (mouseX == chosen.get(k).coordinates()[0]  && mouseY == chosen.get(k).coordinates()[1]) {
      print("match Found");
    }
    //println(chosen.get(k).coordinates()[1]);
  }
```

The problem that I am facing is that the console keep printing `match found`even though it's impossible to get the courser at the exact center of the circle.

Any idea what I am doing wrong and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? Start with a simple example that just uses two hard-coded circles.

Comment: Did you solve the problem already? If so, what was the issue? If not, I have a suggestion. Based on the code given I assume you made a 'Circle'-class that has variables x and y for the position. When you call chosen.get(k).coordinates() it returns the super.x/y. However, chosen.get(k) is the instance of the 'Circle', so you should return the x / y instead. I think calling the super might be what causes the false positives. Could you test this and share the result?